# Extract Custom Format From Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a custom cell format like the below:

> 0.0%"(1L)"_);(0.0%"(1L)");--   *);@*)

I am trying to extract the 1L into a cell.

There is another example which it looks like

> 0.0%"(2L)"_);(0.0%"(2L)");-- );@)

I need to determine if it is 2L or 1L.

Comment: What do you mean by extract the 1L?

Comment: I want to be able to display the 1L, because there is another example in which it looks like 0.0%"(2L)"_);(0.0%"(2L)");-- );@) so I need to be able to determine if it is 2L or 1L

Answer (score 1):

A simple UDF maybe:

```
Function WhichOne(ByVal rng As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile
    If InStr(rng.NumberFormat, "1L") > 0 Then
        WhichOne = "1L"
    ElseIf InStr(rng.NumberFormat, "2L") > 0 Then
        WhichOne = "2L"
    Else
        WhichOne = "neither"
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple UDF

```
Function GetFormat(cell As Range) As String
Application.Volatile
If cell.NumberFormat = "General" Then GetFormat = "General": Exit Function
GetFormat = Split(Split(cell.NumberFormat, "%" & Chr(34) & "(")(1), ")")(0)
End Function
```

Comment: My comment about 'General' formatting was more meant to point out that you don't have a "default" value to return for `GetFormat` if that double `Split` returns an error. It could be 'General', or 'Text', or even some other custom number format that's going to return an error.